# Oracle sql - assign value to nulls or keep value if not null

Tags: sql, oracle11g, isnull, notnull

I have this task where I need to assign a value if the value is null.

if its not null then I want to keep the value that is already there.. 
(this is what is stumping me) I know its got to be easy..

Thanks,
Al

Comment: What do you mean:  assign a value
 
Update a table? A variable in PL/SQL?
 
In SQL:  select ... from ... where column_name IS NULL;
 
See the NVL function.
 
NVL lets you replace null (returned as a blank) with a string in the results of a query. If expr1 is null, then NVL returns expr2. If expr1 is not null, then NVL returns expr1.
 
EX: select nvl(last_name, 'Unknown') from customer;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Coalesce()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm) is what you should use, it's part of the ansi-99 standard as well.

```
Update [Table] Set
   Col1 = coalesce(Col1, @Col1Val)
  ,Col2 = coalesce(Col2, @Col2Val)
Where ...
```

Comment: Without have `where col is null`, all rows will be updated, even the ones containing a value (they will be updated with the existing value). With `where col is null`, there would be no need to coalesce.

Comment: @Glenn The where clause is elided.  Your solution only works for a single column per statement.  If you wanted to update more than one field, you would need an update statement for each.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE myTable
  SET myCol = myDefaultValue
  WHERE myCol IS NULL;
```